Cast to associated type of generic type that conforms to protocol
protocol MyProtocol {
    associatedtype MyAssociatedType
}

struct MyModel: MyProtocol {
    typealias MyAssociatedType = String
}

struct MyObject<U> {
    let myProperty: U
}

struct MyStruct<T, U> {
    init(someObject: MyObject<U>) {
        if let typeThatConformsToMyProtocol = T.self as? any MyProtocol.Type {
            let data = someObject.myProperty as? typeThatConformsToMyProtocol.MyAssociatedType
            // throws 'Cannot find type 'typeThatConformsToMyProtocol' in scope'
        }
    }
}

In this code snippet I need to check if T conforms to MyProtocol. If yes, myProperty has to be cast to MyAssociatedType if possible.
I'm currently not sure how to achieve this. In my view, if T conforms to MyProtocol I should be able to access the underlying associated type, right?

If you're trying to do this, you're probably heavily misusing protocols and should redesign your system. You're going to bump into a lot of limitations because this is not what protocols are for.
That said, it is possible to do what you're suggesting at compile-time by constraining the init with where:
struct MyStruct<T, U> {
    init(someObject: MyObject<U>) where T: MyProtocol, U == T.MyAssociatedType {
    }
}

And you can do it partially at compile time and partially at runtime:
struct MyStruct<T, U> {
    init(someObject: MyObject<U>) where T: MyProtocol{
        if let data = someObject.myProperty as? T.MyAssociatedType { ... }
    }
}

Trying to constrain T: MyProtocol at runtime doesn't make a lot of sense, since T is fixed at compile time. There may be some fragile trickery that will allow it, but it will tend to bite you in surprising ways, and I don't know it.
But again, if you're trying to do this, you're almost certainly on the wrong path. This can be done for fun and education, but all of these approaches are very fragile. The point of protocols is to avoid lots of conditional logic, not add it.
